# Android Studio generating hundreds of duplicate " 2" files

Tags: android-studio, icloud

From time to time, I see my entire build artifacts directory populated with duplicate files whose names all contain " 2".

```
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher_background 2.png
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_background 2.png
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher_background 2.png
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher_background 2.png
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_launcher_background 2.xml
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher_background 2.png
./testapp/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_background 2.png
./testapp/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/org/efalk/testapp/BuildConfig 2.java
./testapp/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/debug/package-aware-r 2.txt
...
```

These look like the kinds of files that iCloud generates when it can't resolve differences between versions of files during sync, and my working directory *is* stored in iCloud ($HOME/Documents/Android/) but I'm not doing anything that should be causing out-of-sync files.

This causes my builds to fail with a complaint about "BuildConfig 2.java".

Is there something I should do, other than move my project out of iCloud?

Comment: I've never seen that before, but I did recently come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58595715) that describes similar behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving my development file out of the iCloud did the trick for me.

Comment: I guess that's the issue then. Stupid Android Studio.